# How to detect click farms in views for a website

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a blog-like website where users can visit other users messages, and the number of views of that message are recorded. I am asking this because I don't know how I could handle click farms, where a user clicks someone's message over and over again and increases the views unfairly. These are the options I considered:

**1st option**

In the MySQL database, the Messages would be stored in this table.

```
Message(massageId, writerId, body, views)
```

And every time a user clicks on the message I run this query:

```
UPDATE Message 
SET views = views + 1
WHERE messageId = ?
```

Of course, the messageId would come from a GET request when the message is clicked.
This option works but I am exposed to malicious users clicking unlimited times on a message increasing the views without control.

**2nd option**

This time in the database I could have two tables:

```
Message(massageId, writerId, body)

Views(viewId, messageId, visitorId)
```

Every time a user clicks on the message I would check if the user has already viewed this message:

```
SELECT viewId 
FROM Views 
WHERE visitorId = ? AND messageId = ?
```

If this query returns a row, then I would not increase the views. Otherwise, I would increase the views by inserting the viewing:

```
INSERT INTO Views
VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

This option prevents click farms, so a user can only increase the views of a message once. But this also creates a table of views which records every viewing, so it's going to grow extremely quickly.

Is it worth it having another table to prevent click farms, maybe risking efficiency and storage since the new table will be very long? If you have any other ideas I'm more than happy to hear them.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes the views column redundant, I will edit it.

Comment: Limit the number of views that count per-day, per-user. That will help cap the storage size. You could also explore storing that data in some other form that's more compact, like stripping the "viewId" if it's not necessary to index each view.

Comment: That is a really good idea! Do you think I could do it by adding a $_SESSION variable that stores the number of messages the user views, and when it gets to a certain number stop storing the views, then reset that $_SESSION value after a certain amount of time?